# Dynamically adding component in relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an xml structure like,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:minWidth="20dp"
    android:text="05"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    style="android:textViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:minWidth="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt2"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:minWidth="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
...
```

As I need this TextView to be dynamically added to View. I am trying to convert same in onCreate() method like below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Drawable rounded_corners = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corners);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainrelativeactivity);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(rel);
    tv.setText("ABC");
    tv.setBackground(rounded_corners);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);

    tv = new TextView(this);
    rel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(rel);
    tv.setText("DEF");
    tv.setBackground(rounded_corners);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);

}
```

But I don't understand how to set `layout_alignParentLeft`,`layout_marginTop` and most concern is `layout_toRightOf` part?

If some one helpful to direct me to example like this then it will be great...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the rule with the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to accomplish what u want..

Something like this

For aligning a view to right of an another view

```
rel.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
```

For aligning a view to the left in parent

```
rel.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

For giving margins

```
rel.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But if I do `tv.getId()` it gives me -1 and to generate id, if I do `tv.generateViewId()` still it's not generating same. And cause of it both text are displaying one above another. Is there any other way to resolve the same?